# Backbutton issue when opened FileOpenPicker in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am working in windows phone 8.1 application. i opened a fileOpenpicker used the following code.

```
FileOpenPicker _fileOpen = new FileOpenPicker();
view = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView();
_fileOpen.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
_fileOpen.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
_fileOpen.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
_fileOpen.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

[image]

At this point when I press back button, it goes to the main page of the application, not to the page form where it was navigated. Please help

Comment: Can you show us the code where you handle BackPressedButton event?

Comment: I haven't handled the BackPressButton event at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add `IFileOpenPickerContinuable` interface in the page where you try to select files.Also this will get the result of file selection in this following method.

```
public async void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
{
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = args.Files;
}
```

Take a look at this file open picker sample at MSDN

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn614994.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1) Open App.xaml.cs file

2) Add this code to the App() method

```
HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

3) Paste this code somewhere below App() method

```
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame.Content is MainPage)
        {
            rootFrame.BackStack.Clear();
        }
        else if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

What it does is it adds handling of pressing the hardware button and if user is on the *MainPage* then you leave an app.
If you have underlined words in these lines of code then just set your text cursor on one of them and press Ctrl + '.' -> then select the first option from menu to add libraries (*using* expressions).